# scala accepting generic classes

Tags: scala, generics

I have two case classes

```
abstract  class MainClass
case class Acc(x:String, y:String)  extends MainClass
case class Bcc(x:String, y:String)  extends MainClass
```

I need to write a generic fucntion that will take either one of them and return a list of the same case class, something similar to :

```
def f1[T <: MainClass ]():List[T]={
val o1 = new Acc("sss","ddd").asInstanceOf[T]
List(o1)
}
```

the only problem is that I am hard-coding the type class "Acc" . My question is How do I make the f1 method instantiate the generic class T instead of Acc or Bcc

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can use ClassTag to keep meta information about Class during
>   runtime.

```
import scala.reflect._


abstract  class MainClass
case class Acc(x:String, y:String)  extends MainClass
case class Bcc(x:String, y:String)  extends MainClass

object  Boot extends App {



  def f1[T <: MainClass : ClassTag ]():List[T]={
    val o1 = classTag[T].runtimeClass.getConstructor(classOf[String], classOf[String]).newInstance("sss","ddd").asInstanceOf[T]
    List(o1)
  }

 val list =  f1[Acc]

}
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, FWIW. I don't think this is a unreasonable answer to the question—I just don't think it's the _best_ answer.

Comment: I'm the downvoter, I don't think run-time reflection is reasonable specially for a use case where avoiding it is so trivial.

Comment: It depends, classTag solution is definitely the simplest and for some use cases when you can not deliver type classes the only one but of course it's not a solid.

Answer (score 11):

While the `ClassTag` solution may work for you, relying on runtime reflection is a code smell, and it can actually get you into real trouble. Suppose you end up with a new subclass like this (defined either by you or by someone else using your code):

```
case class Ccc(x: String, y: String, i: Int)  extends MainClass
```

Now when someone writes `f1[Ccc]`—and there's no indication in the method signature that they shouldn't—their program will crash at runtime with a `NoSuchMethodException`.

There's a much safer way to do this kind of thing, and while it requires a bit of boilerplate-writing for you, it's transparent to people using your code down the line (including yourself). First you define a [type class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class) that describes how to create an instance of some specific subclass of `MainClass`:

```
trait MainClassFromStrings[T <: MainClass] {
  def apply(x: String, y: String): T
}
```

Then you write some type class instances:

```
implicit def AccFromStrings: MainClassFromStrings[Acc] =
  new MainClassFromStrings[Acc] {
    def apply(x: String, y: String) = Acc(x, y)
  }

implicit def BccFromStrings: MainClassFromStrings[Bcc] =
  new MainClassFromStrings[Bcc] {
    def apply(x: String, y: String) = Bcc(x, y)
  }
```

And now you can write your `f1` pretty cleanly:

```
def f1[T <: MainClass](implicit fs: MainClassFromStrings[T]) =
  List(fs("sss", "ddd"))
```

And then:

```
scala> f1[Acc]
res0: List[Acc] = List(Acc(sss,ddd))

scala> f1[Bcc]
res1: List[Bcc] = List(Bcc(sss,ddd))
```

But you get a nice compile-time error if you try `f1[Ccc]`.

Type classes are pretty widely used in Scala (including in the standard library)—searching Stack Overflow for [`"type classes" in Scala`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22type%20classes%22%20in%20scala) will turn up lots of examples and discussion.

Comment: maybe implicit conversion can be put into the companion object and injected into the argument, so implicit scope can be restricted.

Comment: @Cloudtech: There's no implicit conversion here, and I'm not sure what you mean by "injected into the argument", but you could (and probably should) put the instances into the `MainClassFromStrings` companion object—I was just trying to keep the answer simple.